# How can seam-gen be customized to support another database?

Tags: java, seam, informix

I would like to create an application from a database schema using seam-gen; unfortunately Informix isn't supported out of the box.

Where can I add another db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make these steps:

- Run seam setup to generate setup file. These file will be written in seam-gen/build.properties.
- You can edit these file and change some values like:

```
    hibernate.dialect
    hibernate.connection.url
    hibernate.connection.username
    hibernate.connection.driver_class
    database.exists
    hibernate.connection.dataSource_class
    driver.jar
```

- Buid project.

I always use seam with MySQL but I hope it helps.

Comment: Actually I edited seam-gen/build.xml to provide Informix as an option with default settings. But your approach should work also.